# Select count of value

Tags: mysql, sql

I have table, where I store rate of blog posts (liked, disliked) and I need to select count of likes and dislikes for each post (and of course JOIN it on table with blogs :) )
The table look like this:

```
+---------+---------+-----------+
| id_user |  rate   |  id_blog  |
+---------+---------+-----------+
|    1    |  like   |     1     |
|    2    | dislike |     1     |
|    3    |  like   |     1     |
|    6    |  like   |     1     |
               .    
               . 
               .
```

How is the best to to this? Or is bad idea to realize it like this?

Comment: Why not use a 1 or 0 for like/dislike rather than a string.

Comment: What is your question? Are you asking for SQL or schema design?

Comment: Where is the post identifier specified?

Comment: You mean Select id_user, count(*) FROM table where rate = 'like' ? and than using the id_users selected, do a join with your other table..

Comment: @kkuilla For SQL syntax

Comment: @AndreiAndrei Yes, but I need to select dislikes too ...

Comment: @Tommo1977: maybe he will want to use a 'very disliked' rate in the future :) joking

Comment: @Tommo1977: I just think like and dislike ("and no feeling") has higher information value, then rate: 3.68 ...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use:

```
SELECT 
  id_blog, 
  SUM(rate='like') AS like_count, 
  SUM(rate='dislike') AS dislike_count 
FROM 
  blog_posts 
GROUP BY 
  id_blog
```